# phonegap application multiple languages

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I'm developing phonegap application for android and ios. 
I have option to change languages or set default language.
how can I store the value, that one chose?

```
$("input[name=lang]:radio").change(function () {
    lang = $('input:radio[name=lang]:checked').val();
navigator.app.loadUrl('file:///android_asset/www/index.html');
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` for this.

```
localStorage.setItem('Mari_mari_app_language', yourNewLanguage);
```

and

```
var language = localStorage.getitem('Mari_mari_app_language');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works after adding 'window.' before localStorage.